# Return an array with the following format: [lowestKey, highestKey]

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return an array with the following format: [lowestKey, highestKey]. What would be the easiest way to go about doing this? I went with a for loop (that is not finished yet), and am kind of at a loss as to what to do next?

For clarity: the function is supposed to accept an object and return an array of lowest and highest key.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
function minMaxKeyInObject(arr) {
  let min = arr[0].y, max = arr[0].y;

  for (let i = 1, len=arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    let v = arr[i].y;
    min = (v < min) ? v : min;
    max = (v > max) ? v : max;
  }

  return [min, max];
}

console.log(
  minMaxKeyInObject({ 2: 'a', 7: 'b', 1: 'c', 10: 'd', 4: 'e' }),
  minMaxKeyInObject({ 1: 'Elie', 4: 'Matt', 2: 'Tim' })
  );
```

I am trying to return `[1, 10]` and `[1, 4]`

Comment: You're passing *objects* to the function, not arrays.

Comment: @Pointy For clarity: the function is supposed to accept an object and return an array of lowest and highest key.

Comment: What is the `y` property you're trying to access?

Comment: @CodyWirth well plain objects don't have a `.length` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys, then just return an Array with [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) / [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

```js
function minMaxKeyInObject(obj) {
  let keys = Object.keys(obj);

  return [Math.min(...keys), Math.max(...keys)];
}

console.log(
  minMaxKeyInObject({2: 'a',7: 'b',1: 'c',10: 'd',4: 'e'}),
  minMaxKeyInObject({1: 'Elie',4: 'Matt',2: 'Tim'})
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use length on a JS object. You need to iterate thru your keys and find the max and min

```
function minMaxKeyInObject(arr) {
  let min, max;
  let first = true;
  for (var keyval in arr) {
    if (first) {
      min = keyval;
      max = keyval;
      first = false;
    } else {
      let v = keyval;
      min = (v < min) ? v : min;
      max = (v > max) ? v : max;
    }
  }
  return [min, max];
}
```

Comment: Instead of the `first` variable, just initialize `min` and `max` to `Object.keys(arr)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

//set up 2 containers that will hold the lowest and highest keys from the object
//set containers to Infinity to account for edge cases such as if there is no key-value pair in the given object or if there's only 1 key-value pair

```
function minMaxKeyInObject(someObject){
    
    let minKey = Infinity; 
    let maxKey = -Infinity;
    
    /*
    loop through the object and convert each key to a number since every object in JavaScript is an associative array whose keys are strings.
    Then compare each key with the maxKey and minKey. If it is a larger value, then maxKey will be set equal to that key. If it is smaller, then minKey will be set equal to that key.  
    */
    for (const key in someObject){
    //change the key in the object from a string to a number
        let keyAsNum=+key;
    //
        if (keyAsNum>maxKey){
            maxKey=keyAsNum;
        }
        if (keyAsNum<minKey){
            minKey=keyAsNum;
        }
    }
    return [minKey, maxKey];
}
```